# Why is stack unwinding guaranteed only for handled exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

C++ [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) says (`[except.handle]/9`):

> If no matching handler is found, the function std::terminate() is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to std::terminate() is implementation-defined

For example, behavior of code below (will it print `S::~S()` or not) is implementation defined:

```
struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "S::S()" << std::endl; }
    ~S() { std::cout << "S::~S()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    throw std::runtime_error("exception");
}
```

I would like to know *in-depth*: why is it implementation defined? Why a context cannot be unwinded up to its entry before `std::terminate()` is called if an exception is uncaught (which is similar to `try{ ... } catch(...) { throw; }` in the top-level function)? At a glance, such behavior is much clearer and safer in consistence with RAII.

Answer (score 12):

If an exception isn't caught, `std::terminate` is called. We failed so bad the host environment needs to step in and (maybe) clean up after us. Unwinding the stack in this case is like giving a helmet to a kamikaze pilot.

So for a hosted environment, it may make more sense to just do nothing and let the host clean up.

Now, if you are in a stand alone implementation, and are throwing exceptions, then there is no one to clean up after you. An implementation should preform stack unwinding in this case, because that's what is supposed to clean up the mess.

The standard leaves it to the implementation to facilitate these two very different execution environments.

---

Like @Matteo pointed out, `std::terminate` is called before any potential unwinding because you can setup a handler for it. And that handler can do something useful with the stack state, so long as the stack isn't unwound yet.

Comment: "giving a helmet to a kamikaze pilot". That's a new one for me.

Comment: @AndyG - I can't take credit. Heard it in a talk Alexandrescu gave. It was about `noexcept` but the principle remains :)

Comment: Also, `std::terminate` being called *before* unwinding is extremely convenient if you set up a custom terminate handler that can log the current exception and its stack trace.

Comment: @MatteoItalia please note, whether or not the stack is unwinded before std::terminate() is called is *implementation defined* and *not guaranteed*.

Comment: @Nevermore - True. But terminate is called in [many different scenarios](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.terminate). For most of them stack unwinding will not happen before the call to terminate.

Comment: @StoryTeller The question is about uncaught exceptions and stack unwinding. And in this context override `std::terminate()` for such purposes is error-prone, isn't it?

Comment: @Nevermore: even just talking about getting a stack trace is way outside the scope of the standard; I'm just saying that allowing `std::terminate` not to unwind allows this to be done given a particular implementation.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Why is it standardized and declared against RAII? Look, compiler is free to implement its own intrinsics (which are out of the standard as well) for such purposes.

Comment: @Nevermore - It's not *against* RAII. It's just a corner case where RAII *may* be redundant. All other cases of calls to `std::terminate` (no need to remind me you asked about a specific one) are very much pro-RAII.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. What if I have resources the host system won't or can't clean? Like database connections or other custom resources? It would make sense to wind the stack back to make sure all resources are freed before terminating. I guess the only sensible way to deal with this is to catch all exceptions in main and re-throw.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili - You won't get a core dump on linux if you do that. Not one with a useful stack trace anyway. So it's hardly that cut and dry, there's trade-offs.

Answer (score 2):

Not the strongest reason per se, but leaving this up to the implementation allows for more optimizations. E.g.:

```
class Foo { /*...*/ };

void f();

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    {
        Foo myFoo;
        f();
    }
}
```

Here, an implementation may choose not to destroy `myFoo` if `f()` throws, which may reduce code size and/or increase performance. The rationale would be if you don't write an exception handler, you don't expect `f()` to throw anyway, and shortcuts may be taken. This may sound a bit weak, but this is similar to `noexcept` (C++11) vs. `throw()` clause (C++98) – removing the requirement to unwind the stack allows for more aggressive optimization.

Comment: Sounds very weak, particularly as this example (the code is directly in `main` and all visible in this TU) is so contrived. I can't imagine a compiler writer would go out of their way to optimise for it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in `main`, if whole program optimization is used, the code could even be in a different TU, but certainly a different function. And it might be impossible to prove that `f()` doesn't throw for the given inputs. You are not by chance saying that small programs need less optimization? ;-)

Comment: That's a big "if"!

Comment: Sure, link time optimization is rarely used (though it is now supported by most major compilers). But I've heard compiler developers say that they would absolutely implement optimizations that break ill-formed code for even a minor performance gain in well-formed code. And I've participated in a discussion where Chandler Carruth talked about how much the mere possibility of stack unwinding can hurt optimization. It sounded almost like he abhorred them. I can see how a compiler dev would not want to make this guarantee on principal grounds as well – code that throws should also catch.

Comment: Of course they'd "want" to but that's not the same as it actually being feasible or worthwhile to spend time doing it